# How to know a lock has been acquired

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I have a common method which is accessed by multiple threads,

```
     public void m(String fileName)
     {         
       FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(fileName);
       FileChannel fc = fos.getChannel();
       fc.tryLock();
       ....
```

Sometimes the fileName might be same in two or more threads and I get an exception when I use tryLock() or lock(). How can I know if a lock has already been acquired?

**Update**:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

class A implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {   
            FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream("file.2txt");
            FileChannel fc = fos.getChannel();
            fc.tryLock();                                

            Thread.sleep(4000);

            fc.close();            
            System.out.println("done");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }
}

public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        new Thread(new A()).start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        new Thread(new A()).start();  
    }
}
```

I get an exception:

```
java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl$SharedFileLockTable.checkList(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl$SharedFileLockTable.add(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(Unknown Source)
    at run.A.run(Test.java:14)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Doesn't `tryLock()` return `null` if it can't acquire the lock?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Wrong `tryLock()`. See the [`FileChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#tryLock()) API.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen Get outta here!

Comment: `A lock object representing the newly-acquired lock, or null if the lock could not be acquired because another program holds an overlapping lock`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I get an exception (updated the question)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Watch your tongue, buddy - I just unlocked mod tools. Imma close and delete all your questions and answers or something. http://0.tqn.com/d/politicalhumor/1/0/1/7/3/demotivational-power.jpg

Comment: @Rnet Javadoc: `OverlappingFileLockException - If a lock that overlaps the requested region is already held by this Java virtual machine, or if another thread is already blocked in this method and is attempting to lock an overlapping region`. Does that apply to you?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, I want to know any other thread has acquired the lock already

Comment: @Rnet It might not be great design, but the exception tells you just that. Catch and handle.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis So I have to synchronize the block, which will block all other threads even though they may be trying to access a different file?

Comment: @Rnet I don't know what your requirements are, but that doesn't seem like the way to go, for the reason your described. Let `FileLock` manage the blockage. IF you try to access the same file, maybe loop, wait, and try again.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I want to multiple threads to read/write a <dynamically generated fileName> safely, I feel polling is not an elegant solution

Comment: @Rnet I've found that it's hard to manage transactional operations on file systems. If you can guarantee that only your application is operating on the destination directory, keep a global synchronized map  to hold filenames which you add/remove to when you want to write/finish writing.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I know if a lock has already been acquired?

The best answer is to use `fc.tryLock();`.  However, it should *not* throw an exception.  It will return `null` if the lock cannot be acquired.  That's the best way to see if the lock is not locked.

To quote from the [javadocs for FileChannel.tryLock()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#tryLock%28%29):

> This method does not block. An invocation always returns immediately, either having acquired a lock on the requested region or having failed to do so. If it fails to acquire a lock because an overlapping lock is held by another program then **it returns null**. If it fails to acquire a lock for any other reason then an appropriate exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Right. So it's behaving as expected, because the user is trying to acquire the lock twice within a single program (returns null if *another* program has the lock, all threads are within one program). I'd hate to ever recommending catching that exception as a way to tell if a lock's already in place. Sounds like you may be best to set up another internal variable within your program to hold the lock state. Or catch the exception and use that to mean "lock is already acquired within this program".